# Does anyone know where the list/database of USB/Thunderbolt accessories authorized to connect in macOS Ventura is stored?

Tags: macos, security, ventura

In macOS Ventura there is a new feature under "Privacy & Security" that allows you to limit how USB devices are connected, similar to iOS. By default it set to:

```
Allow accessories to connect: Ask for New Accessories
```

Clearly, the system now stores a list of connected devices so it doesn't keep asking you. Does anyone know where this is?

Comment: Are you trying to add to it or delete from it on the command line?

Comment: No. Is there a command for that?

Comment: Not sure if this: `defaults read /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist`